# Euro symbol escape outputting: ?€

Tags: c#, escaping, pdfsharp

I am trying to escape the euro symbol `€` in C# with `\u20AC` but for some reason the result is this: `?€`. There is a question mark there. I am using PdfSharp to convert code to a PDF File and I need to use the euro symbol.

I've tried this:

- Pasting the euro symbol without escape
- Using: `.Replace("?", "")`

But both options didn't work.

This is the code to draw a `String` with a euro symbol:

```
gfx.DrawString("‎\u20AC " + myString, normalFont, textColor, 
               new XRect(0, 0, 0, 0), XStringFormats.Default);
```

**NOTE:** Other symbols like `%` are working

**EDIT:**

After applying the advice form PDFSharpNovice I've added this

```
XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode,
    PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
```

This is the new output:

[image: desc]

Comment: Check the Unicode sample on the site and provide an MCVE if the issue persists. There is no general problem using the Euro sign with Unicode in PDFsharp. ASCII symbols like "%" work, but you can test other Unicode symbols or non-ASCII symbols like "ÄÖÜäöüß" http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Unicode-sample.ashx

Comment: @PDFsharpNovice checkout my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the Euro sign.
Your string contains a zero-width Unicode char between the quote and the backslash. When you move through that line with "cursor left" or "cursor right" you will notice that it takes a double-step at this spot.

The invisible zero-width character leads to the question mark. Remove it and you're done.

Update: The "character" was e2 80 8e, LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that existed. +1